creating a word .doc macro for a resize all / picture stack
Hi group I really need someone's assistance in creating a specific macro to make my work reporting more efficient and streamlined. I am definitely not a guru in this area of expertise. I would appreciate help to create a macro that; i have attached a photo of what i am trying to achieve.Resized and stacked images
After I insert multiple pictures in a document. I want the macro to

select all the images

Change the Width of all images so they are the same = InchesToPoints(2)

change the text wrapping to 'square' to all images

Stack the images on top of each other with a small gap between each one

select all images and group together

change the overall grouped image height to 8.3" and width to 3"


i have tried multiple copy and paste example methods from the internet but nothing seems to work for the my project

Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered.

Sub ResizeImage()
'
' ResizeImage Macro
' Selected image(s) are resized to 5 cm in width
'
Dim shape As InlineShape
' iterate all selected shapes
For Each shape In Selection.InlineShapes
' remain aspect ratio
shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
' set with to 2 "
shape.Width = InchesToPoints(2)
Next
End Sub

Hi this is the only macro that i have been able to get working for my problem. the resize all images that i mentioned in step 2. for the remainder of the steps i havent been able to find a code or record one myself, i was hoping someone may be able to help. all the rest has been me manually editing the images and moving them around my hand

here is a macro for image resize and making them square by text wrapping. but i am not sure how to put this code together with the one i just posted above so the they can both run. still looking for another code to then stack the photos like the example i attached. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-code-insert-and-resize-image-with-square-text/2998a8b9-1820-4b86-b0a9-ad207067e1b3

The simplest solution is to place your images in a table.

Please do not post code as a comment. Use the Edit link below your question to add the code to your question.
